# pst-plot and psgraph environment to small

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I try to plot a large spectrum with `pst-plot`, but I cannot create a `psgraph` environment large enough, because the x-axis line is not drawn correctly.

Do you know how to make it work?

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[paper=A3,paper=landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\psset{linewidth=0.1pt}
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(10,10){20cm}{20cm}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the time I am writing this answer, PSTricks does not support hexadecimal number `2a0` in your `{2a0cm}`. So you need to remove the `a` as follows.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[paper=A3,paper=landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\psset{linewidth=0.1pt}
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(10,10){20cm}{20cm}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The a was accidentially there. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see this with up-to-date TL 2016. It looks like that you have a unit setting elsewhere ...

[image]